# if statement not working as I would expect

Tags: excel, vba

I have write a code for data entry in excel vba. I have add some products without using the form, i add them in the sheet directly. The program is supposed to check if the product is already in the list and if it should pop up a message. When i add a product using the form and then i try to add the same product all work fine and the message appears. But for product i add by hand it doesn't make the check and it adds the same product again and again.

My if statement is the below

```
  With Worksheets("Data Entry")


    If (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Data Entry").Cells(6, "B"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Stock").Cells(i, "B")))) _
        And (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Data Entry").Cells(6, "C"))) = UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Stock").Cells(i, "C")))) _
    Then
        MsgBox "Product exists", vbOKCancel
    GoTo telos

    ElseIf (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Data Entry").Cells(6, "B"))) <> UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Stock").Cells(i, "B")))) _
        And (UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Data Entry").Cells(6, "C"))) <> UCase(Trim(Worksheets("Stock").Cells(i, "C")))) _
    Then

        answer = MsgBox("Add new", vbOKCancel)
        If answer = vbCancel Then
            MsgBox "Cancelled!"
            GoTo telos
        Else
         meter2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Stock.Range("A:A"))
         arrayData = VBA.Array(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6)
         Stock.Cells(meter2 + 1, 1).Resize(, 6) = arrayData
         Worksheets("Stock").Cells(i, "G") = Worksheets("Stock").Cells(i, "A") * Worksheets("Stock").Cells(i, "D")
         Worksheets("Stock").Cells(i, "H") = Worksheets("Stock").Cells(i, "A") * Worksheets("Stock").Cells(i, "F")
         MsgBox "Data entry completed"
         GoTo telos
        End If


    End If
End With
Next i

End If


telos:


End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: But your code sends to `telos` label. Where this `telos` is, in your code?

Comment: Can you try changing your code so that you do not use `GoTo`? It is considered very bad practice.

Comment: Is this code in a user form?  If so, you'll need to make a procedure that you can reuse and call it in the worksheet change event.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav what do you mean exactly?